# Best way to store and retrieve user location information

Tags: mysql, database, location

I'm currently building a professional network and although I have manage to get the overall DB structure and data entry figured out, I continue to struggle with how I should build my location table or tables and then how best to query that data to display on a users profile or to be searched upon.

Currently I have a single locations table and that is as far as I have got.

I'm looking for advice on how best to proceed before I invest too much time building something that may prove difficult to manage down the line or which will not work.

***UPDATE:*** to clarify the location data I wish to store and in what format; A user can set a city and country of residence but can specify other cities and countries where they can work. So, in short a user has a primary location and then possibly several locations they can be.

*Currently I am only looking to store specific City, County and Country information. I do not want it to be possible for a user to specify their own location by free-typing. It would be beneficial if I could use the table to populate data entry fields too.*

*However in time I would like to work on developing 'nearby' searching which will require geo location and the story of coordinates.*

The project is built in PHP with a MySQL database.

The site works like this;

- Users register and create a profile.
- Their profile lists info about them, including their location.
- Other users can search based on select fields including another
  user's location.

The database is currently set up as follows;

- User data sits in a users table.
- Profile data sits in a profiles table.
- Profile photos sits in a profile_photos table.
- Gallery Photos sits in a photos table.
- Location data sits ???

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible better suited on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks - i've posted it there too.